# What parameters does MySQL Workbench pass to mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to write a script to automate MySQL backup of a database.  So to determine what I will need, I go into MySQL Workbench, select the Schema, select **Data Export**, set a couple of controls (at the moment: **Export to Self-Contained File** & **Include Create Schema**) and **Start Export**.

**Export Progress** shows me command-line:

```
Running: mysqldump --defaults-file="/tmp/tmpTbhnzh/extraparams.cnf"  --user=*** --host=*** --protocol=tcp --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-triggers "<schema-name>"
```

I need to know what is in that temporary "defaults file" if I'm to replicate whatever it is that MySQL Workbench passes to `mysqldump`.  But the backup completes so quickly and deletes the file that I can't even copy it, of course!

Is there a way I can know just what arguments Workbench is passing to `mysqldump` so I can know I'm generating a good, robust script?  (To be clear: I'm sure I can look up the `mysqldump` documentation to find arguments corresponding to whatever UI items I fill in explicitly, but I'm wondering what other "goodies" MySQL Workbench might know about and put in the parameters file.)

Comment: Why not run the command with a path of your own choosing, and then read the file at your leisure? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Ahhh, Penny drops. I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of digging about in the python scripts (there's one called wb_admin_export.py) and the answer is....not very exciting... it's your password.

It also includes ignore-tables if there are any to ignore.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I had figured that one at minimum must be there!  Are you fairly confident that's all it adds to whatever I have selected in the UI?  If so, I'll mark your reply as Solution.  Thanks.

Comment: There you go - edited the answer for you. I think that's the lot :)

Comment: If anyone is interested, here's the source for the current version: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/6a6c6e4bbb742e37d1c7b5334275e214f230abb7/plugins/wb.admin/frontend/wb_admin_export.py#L164-L286

Comment: [client]
password=DATABASE_PASSWORD
[mysqldump]
ignore-table=DATABASE.TABLE etc